# CSS text-truncate only hides the inner element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

The sample below hides the "In Progress" inside the span element. How can I show it? I am using text-truncate. On the actual output, it looks like this: "Birthday Song  Birthday  Song..." The outcome should be like this: "Birthday Song  Birthday  Song  Birthday...In Progress". I also tried to add text-truncate in the span element but same problem.

[image]

[image]

```css
.event-description {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 60%;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
}

.event {
  color: var(--black);
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  letter-spacing: -.025rem;
  margin-bottom: .62rem;
}

.event span {
  color: var(--indigo);
  font-size: .75rem;
  font-weight: 600!important;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background: var(--indigo-light);
  margin-left: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between event-description">
  <div class="left">
    <h5 class="text-truncate event">Birthday Song Birthday Song Birthday <span>In Progress</span></h5>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
    <button type="button" class="btn details">View Details</button>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: If you only want the `Birthday Song  Birthday  Song  Birthday` part truncated - then you need to put that text into an element of its own, and apply the `text-truncate` class to that. I'd probably put it into a span, and make the h5 itself a flexbox element.

Comment: Your code appears to me exactly as you wish. You didn't say what the `right` and `event` classes do, it's possible that it has something to do with it.

Comment: @Adam I update the post, the first image hides the In Progress, the second one shows the image because there is still room for words or text.

Comment: I would suggest that putting the ellipsis _after_ the "In Progress" pill is a bit odd. It represents the obscured text and should be set next to the truncated text. The pill should come after as it's a separate indicator.

Comment: The Tidy button is your friend. It makes it apparent that you have a minor syntax issue.